# Regex that matches string that starts with but does NOT include

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a Regex that matches any string that starts with "form submit success mail" but does not contain the digits 306

Here's what I've got so far:
/^(?i)(form submit success mail(?!/(306))).*/gm

3 example strings:

```
form submit success mail - 306 - how are you today
form submit success mail - 2019 - this is a test
form submit success mail - 675 - what the
```

The query should match the bottom 2 strings but not the first.

Tested in https://regex101.com/ but doesn't seem to work - any help appreciated.

Comment: You need `(?i)^(form submit success mail)(?!\s*-\s*306).*`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, that works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go with something like

```
^form submit success mail(?!.*306).*$
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, this suggestion also works perfectly. Much appreciated.